# How to send a Mail with Auth Login by TcpClient and Network Streamer?

Tags: c#, authentication, telnet, networkstream

I have found some OpenSource Code for sending Mails by TcpClient, Network Streamer and Stream Reader with the Telnet Report. Because I need to send the Mails with "AUTH LOGIN" I have just modified the founded code, but unfortunately it dosen´t work. I got the response, that the authentication was unsucessfull - but the credentials are definitally right!

Where is my mistake?
Or isn´t it possible to do that, like I try?
In that case, is there any alternative way?

```cs
// create server SMTP with port 25
TcpClient SmtpServ = new TcpClient(servername, 25);
string Data;
byte[] szData;
string CRLF = "\r\n";
string Log = "";

        try
        {
            // initialization
            NetworkStream NetStrm = SmtpServ.GetStream();
            StreamReader RdStrm = new StreamReader(SmtpServ.GetStream());

            // say hello to server and send response into log report
            Data = "ehlo " + servername + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);


/////////////////////////           
//THIS IS MY MODIFIYED PART

            //credentials
            Data = "AUTH LOGIN " + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);

            //username
            Data = username + " " + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);

            // Just wait a sec...
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //password
            Data = password + " " + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);

//END OF MODIFIYED PART    
/////////////////////


            // send sender data
            Data = "MAIL FROM: " + "<" + absender + ">" + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);

            // send receiver data
            Data = "RCPT TO: " + "<" + empfaenger + ">" + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);

            // send DATA
            Data = "DATA " + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);

            // send content data
            Data = "SUBJECT: " + betreff + CRLF + CRLF +
               nachricht + CRLF + "." + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);

            // quit from server SMTP
            Data = "QUIT " + CRLF;
            szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
            NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);

            while (!RdStrm.EndOfStream)
            {
                Log = Log + CRLF + RdStrm.ReadLine();
                Session["log"] = " ++ " + Log.ToString();
            }
```

UPDATE:
The response to my EHLO looks like the following: 
EHLO server 
250-server Hello [xxx.xx.x.xxx] 
250-SIZE 52428800 
250-PIPELINING 
250-DSN 
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
250-STARTTLS 
250-AUTH LOGIN 
250-8BITMIME 
250-BINARYMIME 
250 CHUNKING

After that I send AUTH LOGIN and so on. I also translate the username and password to base64 and pass this to telnet report. When I test it manually in cmd it works, but with my code over C# not

Comment: The SMTP server must advertise `AUTH` support in its `EHLO` response before you can use it. Can you show the contents of the SMTP `EHLO` response in your question?

Comment: Also, in response to your `AUTH LOGIN` command supporting servers respond with `334 VXNlcm5hbWU6` (base64-encoded `Username:`) or `334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6` (base64 encoded `Password:`) to which you respond with your base64 encoded username and base64 encoded password. Be aware that servers compliant with [RFC 4954 SMTP Server Extension for Authentication](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4954.txt) will not support plaintext `AUTH` commands unless you're running over a TLS or STARTTLS-enabled channel.

Comment: The response to my EHLO looks like the following:   EHLO server
250-server Hello [xxx.xx.x.xxx]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH LOGIN
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
After that I send AUTH LOGIN and so on. I also translate the username and password, as described in my first text to base64 and pass this to telnet report. When I test i manually in cmd it works, but with my code over C# not